# How can I solve a CDO problem encounter in R?

Tags: r, cdo-climate

I am using `cdo` in R and I come across the following problem.

```r
Error in system2("cdo", cmd.args, stdout = TRUE) : '"cdo"' not found
[1] "Error in system2(\"cdo\", cmd.args, stdout = TRUE) : '\"cdo\"' not found\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in system2("cdo", cmd.args, stdout = TRUE): '"cdo"' not found>
attr(,"cdo.command")
```

The cdo I am used was installed using this code:

```r
devtools::install_github("markpayneatwork/ClimateOperators")
```

Please, How to solve it? Does someone have an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: The package [github repo](https://github.com/markpayneatwork/ClimateOperators) says that it is an *"R wrapper around the CDO and NCO packages"*. This is vague, certainly, but I believe it is referring to OS-level programs, not R packages. You need to install from both of https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/ and https://nco.sourceforge.net/ into the OS itself, then restart R (possibly RStudio, if you're using it), and _then_ check to ensure that you can use the R package `ClimateOperators`.

Comment: Did you install the dependencies from https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/ and http://nco.sourceforge.net/ as described in the [README](https://github.com/markpayneatwork/ClimateOperators/blob/master/README.md)? Those are things you will need to install yourself; R can't install those for you. Make sure to add them to your system path and restart R after updating your path.